# Django Form Fields based on Model Choices

Tags: django, forms, models

I want to offer form fields based on model choices. So, if in my models:

```
COLORS = (
    ('BLA', 'Black'),
    ('WHI', 'White'),
    ('RED', 'Red'),
    ('BLU', 'Blue'),
)

YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))

class Thing(models.Model):
    stuff = models.ForeignKey(Stuff)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COLORS)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'), max_length=4, choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
```

I want to create two form fields, one whose `<select>` options are `YEAR_CHOICES` and one whose options are `COLORS`. Can you do this using `ModelChoiceField`? Re-defining choices in my `forms.py` does not seem very DRY.. Otherwise, how would you solve this issue?

Something like this is what I had envisioned, but it does not work:

```
class BrowseForm(forms.Form):
    stuff = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stuff.objects.all())
    color = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.color.choices())
    year = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.year.choices())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types))

you can use the `select` widget and specify choices. In your case

`color = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.Select(choices=COLORS))`

However, since you've already defined `color` with `choices` you in fact do not need to do *anything* (other than set the meta of `BrowseForm` to `Thing`) to get this to work. It will default to the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Model form

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BrowseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
```

It would then pull in your choices automatically.